# Almacenar en un Array la suma de filas y columnas en Java

Tags: java, array, array-bidimensional

Tengo una matriz de 4x5 donde genero números aleatorios, y luego otra  de 5x6 donde almaceno los números generados de la matriz de 4x5. El caso es que en la quinta fila debo colocar la suma de las 5 columnas.
La suma de las filas, la he sacado. El programa muestra esto por pantalla. (El 0 de la posición [5][6] mostraría la suma total.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n[][] = new int[4][5]; //Matriz para generar los números aleatorios entre 0 y 100
    int nArray[][] = new int[6][6]; //Array Final
    int sumaFilas = 0, sumaColumnas = 0, sumaTotal = 0;

    //Genera los números aleatorios en 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

            n[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
            nArray[i][j] = n[i][j];
        }

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) { //Columnas

        System.out.print("\t Columna " + j + " ");

    }

    //SumaFilas
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //Filas

        if (i == 4) {
            System.out.println("\n\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print("\n\nFila " + i);
        }
        sumaFilas = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { //Columnas

            System.out.print("\t\t" + nArray[i][j]);
            sumaFilas += nArray[i][j];
            nArray[i][5] = sumaFilas;

        }

    }

    //Suma columnas
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { //Columnas
        sumaColumnas = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //Filas
            sumaColumnas += nArray[i][j];

        }

    }

    System.out.println("");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno voy a realizar un código similar al que hiciste basándome en el ejercicio que planteas:

Te muestro la lógica que utilizo para resolver este problema:

> ```
>     00 01 02 03   // Sumamos todos los 0
>     10 11 12 13   // Sumamos todos los 1
>     20 21 22 23   ...
>     30 31 32 33   ...
>     40 41 42 43   ...
>     Para las columnas es similar a las filas (los 0, los 1, etc)
> ```

Como ves son solo sumas en vertical y horizontal. Ahora veamos el código:

Primeramente instanciamos las matrices que comentas y una variable total para el resultado final:

```
int n[][] = new int[4][5]; //Matriz para generar los números aleatorios entre 0 y 100
int nArray[][] = new int[5][6]; //Array Final
int total = 0;
```

Ahora generamos los números aleatorios para tu matriz, también aprovechamos para realizar la sumatoria total:

```
//Genera los números aleatorios 
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n[i].length; j++) {
        n[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
        nArray[i][j] = n[i][j];
        total += nArray[i][j]; // Sumamos para obtener el total
    }
}
```

Una vez hecho esto pasamos a realizar las sumatorias:

```
// Sumar filas
for (int i = 0; i < nArray.length - 1; i++) {
    int suma = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < nArray[i].length - 1; j++) {
        suma += nArray[i][j];
    }
    nArray[i][n[i].length] = suma; // Asignamos en la ultma posicion de j (columnas)
}
```

---

```
// Sumar columnas
for (int i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++) {
    int suma = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < nArray[i].length - 1; j++) {
        suma += nArray[j][i]; // Invertimos las posiciones para poder sumar de forma horizontal
    }
    nArray[n.length][i] = suma;
}
```

Ahora simplemente igualamos el total a la ultima posición de tu matriz **(OJO que también se hubiera podido hacer esta parte dentro del `for` en las sumatorias)**:

```
// A la ultma posición se agrega el total
nArray[nArray.length - 1][nArray[0].length - 1] = total;
```

Y por ultimo mostramos la matriz armada:

```
// Mostramos la matriz
for (int i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nArray[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(nArray[i][j] + ", ");
        if (nArray.length == j)
            System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

---

**Código completo:**

```
int n[][] = new int[4][5]; //Matriz para generar los números aleatorios entre 0 y 100
int nArray[][] = new int[5][6]; //Array Final
int total = 0;

//Genera los números aleatorios 
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n[i].length; j++) {
        n[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
        nArray[i][j] = n[i][j];
        total += nArray[i][j]; // Sumamos para ibtener el total
    }
}

// Sumar filas
for (int i = 0; i < nArray.length - 1; i++) {
    int suma = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < nArray[i].length - 1; j++) {
        suma += nArray[i][j];
    }
    nArray[i][n[i].length] = suma; // Asignamos en la ultma posicion de j (columnas)
}

// Sumar columnas
for (int i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++) {
    int suma = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < nArray[i].length - 1; j++) {
        suma += nArray[j][i]; // Invertimos las posiciones para poder sumar de forma horizontal
    }
    nArray[n.length][i] = suma;
}

// A la ultma posición se agrega el total
nArray[nArray.length - 1][nArray[0].length - 1] = total;

// Mostramos la matriz
for (int i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nArray[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(nArray[i][j] + ", ");
        if (nArray.length == j)
            System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Obviamente es posible realizar las sumatorias sin separarlos pero ésto es mas o menos para que te hagas una idea de como podrías hacerlo y obviamente mejorarlo.

Espero te sirva, Saludos ;)

Answer (score 1):

Si logro entender quieres que la ultima fila muestre la suma de sus columnas, si es que es esto

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n[][] = new int[4][5]; //Matriz para generar los números aleatorios entre 0 y 100
    int nArray[][] = new int[6][6]; //Array Final
    int sumaFilas = 0, sumaColumnas = 0, sumaTotal = 0;

    //Genera los números aleatorios en 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

            n[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
            nArray[i][j] = n[i][j];
        }

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) { //Columnas

        System.out.print("\t Columna " + j + " ");

    }

    //SumaFilas
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //Filas

        if (i == 4) {
            System.out.println("\n\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print("\n\nFila " + i);
        }
        sumaFilas = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { //Columnas

            System.out.print("\t\t" + nArray[i][j]);
            sumaFilas += nArray[i][j];

            if(j != 5)
            {
                nArray[i][5] = sumaFilas;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    //Suma columnas
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { //Columnas
        sumaColumnas = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //Filas
            sumaColumnas += nArray[i][j];

        }
        System.out.print("\t\t" + sumaColumnas);
    }

    System.out.println("");

}
```